# Issues while converting JavaScript to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I’ve got a huge SCSS style-sheet with some JS files related to it from the UI team in my current project. My task is to convert (reuse) the JS code they created to TypeScript (as the app is in Angular).

Please give me advice, about what is needed to be done to the code below to make it possible. No need to rewrite the whole code for me; if you can just point out what actions have to be done and/or share some references, you will save my life.

As for now, I’ve already added property declarations and tried to change `this.element.querySelector` to `document.querySelector` and so on, but nothing is working as for now…

The whole code (without animations & before conversion) is:

```
class ChangeButton {
constructor(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.container = this.element.querySelector('.switch-box-contents');
  this.content = this.element.querySelectorAll('.switch-box-content');
  this.on = this.container.querySelectorAll('.switch-box-content')[0];
  this.off = this.container.querySelectorAll('.switch-box-content')[1];

  this.ChangeButton = this.element.querySelector('.switch-button');
  this.ChangeButtonContainer = this.ChangeButton.querySelector('.switch-button-contents');
  this.textOn = this.element.querySelectorAll('.switch-button-txt')[0];
  this.textOff = this.element.querySelectorAll('.switch-button-txt')[1];

  this.checkbox = this.element.querySelectorAll('.switch-box-content-input');

  this.ngOnInit();
  this.bind();
}

ngOnInit() {
  const height = this.on.clientHeight;
  this.container.style.height = `${height}px`;
  this.off.classList.remove('-hidden');

  const txtHeight = this.textOn.clientHeight;
  this.ChangeButtonContainer.style.height = `${txtHeight}px`;
  this.textOff.classList.remove('-hidden');
}

contentOff() {
  const height = this.on.clientHeight;
  this.on.classList.remove('-active');
  this.off.classList.add('-active');

  anime({
...
  });

  const containerHeight = this.off.clientHeight;
  anime({
...
  });

  const txtHeight = this.textOn.clientHeight;
  anime({
...
  });
}

contentOn() {
  this.on.classList.add('-active');
  this.off.classList.remove('-active');
  anime({
...
  });

  const containerHeight = this.on.clientHeight;
  anime({
...
  });

  anime({
...
  });
}

getCheckbox() {
  const content = this.container.querySelectorAll('.switch-box-content');
  const activeContent = [].map.call(content, (element) => {
    return element;
  }).filter((element) => {
    return element.classList.contains('-active')
  })[0];
  return activeContent.querySelector('.switch-box-content-input');
}

check(currentCheckbox) {
  if(this.element.classList.contains('-select')) {
    currentCheckbox.checked = false;
    this.element.classList.remove('-checked')
  }
}

handleEvent(e) {
  const on = this.ChangeButton.classList.contains('-on');
  switch (e.type) {
    case 'click' :
      const checkbox = this.getCheckbox();
      if(on) {
        this.ChangeButton.classList.remove('-on');
        this.contentOff();
      } else {
        this.ChangeButton.classList.add('-on');
        this.contentOn();
      }
      this.check(checkbox);
      break;
    case 'change' :
      const chekbox = this.getCheckbox();
      if(chekbox.checked) {
        this.element.classList.add('-checked')
      } else {
        this.element.classList.remove('-checked')
      }
      break;
  }
}

bind() {
  this.content.forEach((content) => {
    content.addEventListener('click', () => {})
  });
  this.ChangeButton.addEventListener('click', this, false);
  this.checkbox.forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', this, false);
  })
}
}
```

Comment: You mean make it more "Angular"? Typescript *is* Javascript. This is too broad and opinion-based for a StackOverflow style question. Some pointers: 1. Look into how you conditionally add classes to elements in the HTML. 2. Look into event handling. 3. Look into form builder. Basically, in the nicest way possible, learn how Angular works.

Comment: You should end up with a block of javascript that has 0 interactions with the DOM. No `classList` manipulation, no `querySelector`. You can achieve all of that through conditional HTML. These are the kinds of things you can learn in the Angular tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: You needed to learn about NgClass link: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass, ViewChild: link: 
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild and Element reference example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftvwwq

Comment: Thank you, will try to rewrite this basing on your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a large part of this is class based and added / removed on user click. I would add booleans in your typescript file for each of these and then use `[ngClass]="boolean ? 'yourClassName' : ''"`. You can then add click event listeners to toggle the booleans - which in turn will toggle your classes.

For example :

```
<div [ngClass]="boolean ? 'active' : 'inactive'" (click)="boolean = !boolean"></div>
```

The same kind of thing can be done with style and individual style attributes.

```
<div [style.height]="boolean ? '10px' : '5px'" (click)="boolean = !boolean"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your solution may work, let me try it. Thank you!